# Sorting JSON data that comes from Retrofit2 on API Level 15

Tags: android, json, sorting, compare, retrofit2

i am new in retrofit . i was using Comparator for sorting my json but i find out that this code Added from api 24 . How can i sort my data for api 15 . 
I dont want to sort data before getting it in mysql and i want to do it by android coding .

this is my sample data

```
[
  {
    "id": "1", 
    "name": "name1", 
    "lastname": "lastname1", 
    "rank": "1", 
   }, 
   {
    "id": "2", 
    "name": "name2", 
    "lastname": "lastname2", 
    "rank": "10", 
   },
   {
    "id": "20", 
    "name": "name20", 
    "lastname": "lastname20", 
    "rank": "105", 
   }
}
```

and some other question :

how do i delete coming data from retrofit that have one parameter null?

how to get the object that has rank 105?

Comment: first parse JSON into POJO (Java model classes), and then sort the list of POJO

Comment: `I dont want to sort data before getting it in mysql` - Why not sort it in MySQL? Wouldn't that simplify your Android code?

Comment: because im getting json from public site and have no access to the database

Answer (score 0):

Get your response in any model like

Like

List data;

where Response is

public class Response {

```
    public int id;
    public String name;

    boolean isValid() {
        return id > 0 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(name);
    }

}
```

and filter invalid response like

```
     ListIterator iterator = data.listIterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Response response = (Response) iterator.next();
            boolean success = response.isValid();

            if (!success) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
```